# Getting rid of duplicated data in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, grid

I am getting duplicated data within my `GridView`, while pulling info from a SQL Server. I am using stored procedures and using some C# to set the parameters then using the `SqlDataSource` to put the sql data from the stored procedure into a `GridView`. I have looked at some other problems just like mine, but the SQL scripting was different than mine. I also know that my C# code works just fine, but I will post that also,

Here is the code:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
    people.name, comage.age, grad.date
FROM 
    people
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT age, MAX(term)[term] 
     FROM comage GROUP BY date) comage ON people.term = comage.term
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT date, MAX(term)[term] 
     FROM grad GROUP BY date) grad ON people.term = grad.term
WHERE 
    people.ID = @ID
ORDER BY 
    LastName
```

**ASP.net:**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server"></GridView>
```

**C# code:**

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "prcedureName";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter param = null;
    param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID",System.Data.SqlDataType.NChar,255);
    param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.value = in; //in is a string of some value
    cmd.Connection = con; //con is a SqlConnection of some sort
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    SqlCommandBuilder command = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    adp.Fill(data);
    grid.DataSource = data;
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    grid.DataBind();
```

Here are the tables:

**people** table:

```
    --------------------
    |name  | ID | term |
    --------------------
    |jeff  | 0  |   A  |
    |Jake  | 1  |   B  |
    --------------------
```

**comage** table:

```
    --------------------
    |Age  |   Term     |
    --------------------
    |23   |    A       |
    |25   |    B       |
    --------------------
```

**grad** table:

```
    --------------------
    | Date |    Term   |
    --------------------
    | DEC  |     A     |
    | SUM  |     B     |
    --------------------
```

Comment: [SELECT DISTINCT . . . ;](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) -- No expert myself though.

Comment: I did find another person with the same problem as me, but he was using SELECT DISTINCT originally and still had the problem... still going to try it though.

Comment: yea, it didn't work for me, but thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: This is a SQL Query issue, not a C# one.  I'll see if I can rework your query, because you should never do selects as columns.

Comment: I know you shouldn't do selects as columns, but I don't know any other way to get the whole column into the grid view.

Comment: The way that you are aggregating your comage and grad tables will definately produce cartesian products.  I would have expected your aggregates to be reversed.  For example, if your comage data looked like (Age,Term)(23,A)(23,B)(25,A)(25,B) your aggregate would produce: (Age, Term)(23,B)(25,B)  and that would result in (Name,Age,Date)(Jake,23,SUM)(Jake,25,SUM).  Is that what you preferred?  Two rows for Jake?

Comment: None of your tables have date columns, so your selects doesn't work.

Comment: @Chizl often times SQL is case-insensitive, but this depends on the configuration of the collation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't have your aggregates backwards in your SQL?  I would have expected it to be written more like this:

```
SELECT people.name, Max(comage.age) age, Max(grad.date) date
FROM   people
INNER JOIN comage ON people.term = comage.term
INNER JOIN grad ON people.term = grad.term
WHERE people.ID = @ID
GROUP BY people.name
ORDER BY LastName
```

Which would produce a result set like this:

```
name | age | date
------------------
Jeff |  23 | DEC
Jake |  25 | SUM
```

Comment: I agree with you, the aggregation didn't make any sense to me either

Answer (score 0):

I only get one record, based on the ID I submitted.

```
DECLARE @People TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(10), ID INT, Term VARCHAR(10));
DECLARE @Comage TABLE (Age INT, Term VARCHAR(10));
DECLARE @Grad TABLE ([Date] VARCHAR(10), Term VARCHAR(10));
DECLARE @ID INT;

SET @ID = 0;

INSERT INTO @People VALUES ('Jeff', 0, 'A');
INSERT INTO @People VALUES ('Jake', 1, 'B');

INSERT INTO @Comage VALUES (23, 'A');
INSERT INTO @Comage VALUES (25, 'B');

INSERT INTO @Grad VALUES ('DEC', 'A');
INSERT INTO @Grad VALUES ('SUM', 'B');

SELECT age, MAX(term) [term]
INTO #Comage
FROM @Comage 
GROUP BY [Age]

SELECT [Date], MAX(term) [term] 
INTO #Grad
FROM @Grad GROUP BY [Date]

SELECT 
    p.name, c.age, g.[Date]
FROM 
    @People p
INNER JOIN #Comage c
    ON c.term = p.term
INNER JOIN #Grad g
    ON g.term = p.term
WHERE 
    p.ID = @ID

DROP TABLE #Comage
DROP TABLE #Grad
```